# Cannot add an usb disk to the storage pool in Windows Home server v1

Tags: usb, windows-home-server

Our WHSv1 file server is almost full, so I took an USB HDD that was lying around (ie: I was using it on another computer, data and partitions are there), and I went to the WHS console to add it to the storage pool.

Surprisingly, the disk does not appear in the list, but if I connect via RDP, i can access it.

What's the problem? Does the disk need to be partitionless or unformatted to be added?

Comment: Despite the "server" in the name, WinHomeServer questions are better asked on Superuser.

Comment: Despite the "home" in the name, I use it in my workplace, because of the useful DE and the cheap price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was scheduling demigrator.exe (drive extender migrator) to be off in peak hours (we use an ancient "killer app" from aldus that adobe refuses to update - has a bug and crashes on save if the server is laggy)

Of course when adding a new drive to the pool, i enabled demigrator, but apparently requires a reboot after enabling.

So, the solution is:

1. Enable demigrator if you set it disabled (i set it disabled at boot for having a quicker boot time)
2. Reboot
3. Add drive